# Force WCF XML Serializer to include empty strings

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have the following property in an `struct` being returned by a WCF service:

```
[XmlAttribute]
public string BATCHID;
```

In cases where the value of BATCHID is the empty string, the serialization excludes the property from the resulting XML as if it was never included in the object to begin with.  How can I force the serializer to always include this property, even if it is the empty string?

EDIT:  I am using the base XML serializer and not the DataContract serializer so EmitDefaultValues is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `EmitDefaultValue = true`:

```
[XmlAttribute, DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=true)]
public string BATCHID_SCHED;
```

The `EmitDefaultValue` cannot be used with the xml serializer.

I think the only way is to implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface and manually serialize/deserialize all the fields/properties of your class:

```
public class Test:IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Prop;

    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Prop", Prop ?? "");
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        if(reader.HasAttributes)
        {
            Prop = reader.GetAttribute("Prop");
        }
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The DataMember attribute allow applies when the DataContract serialization is used.  Since we are using the basic XML serialization model this does not appear to be solving the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I am serializing XML strings from vb.net code in VS2010

If in the class definition I have:

```
<XmlElement("XML_LogonMechanism", IsNullable:=True)> Public LogonMechanism As String
```

then the output looks like this:

```
 <XML_LogonMechanism xsi:nil="true" />
```

If, in the code, I set

```
 myClass.LogonMechanism = ""
```

Then the output includes:

```
<XML_LogonMechanism />
```